# How To Align Text And Images Within A H3 Element

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment, blogger

I would like to align an image and the text that appears alongside it. Currently the image is where I would like it, in the middle, however the text "Back To Top" appears much lower down than the image. Ideally I would like the text to be moved up and become aligned with the image. I have tried wrapping the two elements in separate divs and a classes but nothing seems to work.

I have included the code below:

```
<h3 class='copyright'>&#169;  2015 - 2016 Blankesque . All rights reserved . <a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/policies.html'>Policies</a>

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js'/>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var offset = 300;
var duration = 500;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() &gt; offset) {
jQuery(&#39;.backtotop&#39;).fadeIn(duration);
} else {
jQuery(&#39;.backtotop&#39;).fadeOut(duration);
}
});

jQuery(&#39;.backtotop&#39;).click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
jQuery(&#39;html, body&#39;).animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
return false;
})
});
</script>

<a class='backtotop' href='#'>Back To Top<img height='25px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/C7FFCDAA-9694-451B-89B4-3B0BF8FC8BE9_zpsi7rqccwe.gif' width='25px'/></a>
</h3><div><br/></div><div><br/></div>
```

My blog URL is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com

Comment: Create a div id for the text and make it with CSS be aligned at the top of the image.

Comment: Do you actually have `jQuery(&#39;.backtotop&#39;)` in your code or did you mean to write `jQuery('.backtotop')`?

Comment: Yes I have jquery('.backtotop') in my code however  for whatever reason it copied incorrectly on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches you can take.

If you don't need to support IE8/IE9, you can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), and give the `.backtotop` class CSS rules of `display: flex` and `align-content: center` and they should align up.

You can also put the link text in a `<span>` tag and give that `span` tag CSS properties of `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: And use line-height to adjust further